# Fatorial com recursividade

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer um programa que calcula a fatorial de um número usando recursividade dentro do main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    float numero;
    int valorA = atoi(argv[1]);
    char var1[10];
    itoa(valorA-1, var1, 10);
    if (valorA <= 1)
        return(1);
    else{
        numero = valorA * main(argc, var1);
        return numero;
    }




    printf("Fatorial de %d = %.2f", atoi(argv[1]), numero);
}
```

Quando vou passar o número como argumento no prompt de comando ocorre um erro, dizendo que o programa parou de funcionar. Qual o problema com o meu código?

Comment: Aproveitando, dê uma lidinha em [tour] só para conhecer o modelo do site, e em [ask] tem umas dicas de como elaborar melhor as próximas perguntas que fizer, para aumentar a chance de solução. Aqui tem [umas dicas para formatar o código](/http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) caso precise.

Comment: Por que a recursividade precisa ser feita com a main?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei uma estrategia diferente pra pegar o numero, mas como o seu exemplo nao tem o fatorial em si, talvez essa forma seja mais facil pra voce, utilizando o scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int genFatorial(int n) {
    if(n) {
        return n * genFatorial(n - 1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int fatorial = genFatorial(num);
    printf("%d\n", fatorial);

    return 0;
}
```

Essa é uma solucao bem simples pra esse problema, eu te sugiro usar uma funcao auxiliar ao inves de chamar de novo a funcao main tambem.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu sugeriria o uso do `unsigned int` só.

Comment: Sim, seria uma otimizacao legal :P Boa ideia, usei int pela 'simplicidade' mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Apresentando outra solução para o problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fat (int n)
{
  int res = 1;

  while (n > 1) {
    res = res * n;
    n--;
  }

return res;
}

int main () 
{
  unsigned int n;

  printf("Entre com o valor de n: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Fatorial de %d = %d\n", n, fat(n) );

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No problema ele especifica que precisa que o método seja recursivo.